# glDatePicker display multiple calendars in progressive months

Tags: jquery, html, css, calendar

I am using the newest release of glDatePicker. I am trying to display multiple calendars at the same time in a row all with their own start date.

I need each calendar to be +1 month of the last so that I have 3 progressive months. I have looked and looked and cannot find out how to do it.

I feel like it needs to be something like `NewStartdate: currentMonth(+1month),` but have no idea how its really needed to be marked up. Here is what I have:

HTML:

```
<div class="multi-calendars">
 <div class="single-calendar-outer">
   <input type="text" class="single-calendar" id="example1" />
 </div>
 <div class="single-calendar-outer">    
   <input type="text" class="single-calendar" id="example2" />
 </div>
 <div class="single-calendar-outer">
   <input type="text" class="single-calendar" id="example3" />
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.multi-calendars {
margin-top: -300px;
}
.single-calendar {
width:300px;
border:none;
color:#fff;
height:305px;
}
.single-calendar-outer {
height:305px;
 display:inline;
margin:5px;
visibility:hidden;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$(window).load(function()
{

    // Example #1 - First Month
    $('#example1').glDatePicker(
    {
            showAlways: true,
            cssName: 'flatwhite',
            specialDates: [
    {
        date: new Date(2014, 1, 8),
        repeatMonth: false
    },
    {
        date: new Date(2014, 1, 9),
        repeatYear: false
    }, 
    {
        date: new Date(2014, 1, 10),
        repeatYear: false
    }, 
    {
        date: new Date(2014, 1, 11),
        repeatYear: false
    }, 
   ]
    });
                 // Example #2 - Second Month
    $('#example2').glDatePicker(
    {
            showAlways: true,
            setStartDate: new Date(2014, 2, 1),
            cssName: 'flatwhite',
            specialDates: [
    {
        date: new Date(2014, 2, 10),
        repeatMonth: false
    },
    {
        date: new Date(2014, 2, 11),
        repeatYear: false
    }, 
    {
        date: new Date(2014, 2, 22),
        repeatYear: false
    }, 
   ]
    });
 // Example #3 - Third Month
    $('#example3').glDatePicker(
    {
            showAlways: true,
            cssName: 'flatwhite',
            specialDates: [
    {
        date: new Date(2014, 3, 15),
        repeatMonth: false
    },
    {
        date: new Date(2014, 3, 16),
        repeatYear: false
    }, 
   ]
    });

});
```

[HERE IS THE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2jCrL/12/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the start of your $document.ready use :

```
var month=0;//Or whatever value you set programmatically based on the value derived from your business logic 

$(document).ready(function()
{
 var month=0;

 .... selectedDate: new Date(2014, month, 1),
```

Check here but i have not validated all the logic like What date needs to be selected in that month :`http://jsfiddle.net/J8kbG/19/`